# SQLite - How to define Default value of column in Create Table statement taking reference of other column value

Tags: sqlite

I an using SQLite database and wanted to create a table like following:

`Create Table EMPLOYEE (
  [FirstName] [varchar](50),
  [LastName] [varchar](50), 
  [FullName] [varchar](150) AS ([FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName])
  );`

Can it is possible to have Default value of any column (like `FullName`) referring to values of other columns present in same table.

**UPDATED:**

I tried forming CREATE TABLE statement using these IFNULL and COALESCE function but every time its failing. How should i write such CREATE TABLE statement which will have computed column. If such Computed column in CREATE statement is not supported then how should i achieve such requirement. Can anybody please give me an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DEFAULT` value expression must be a constant expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and referring to other column values makes it non-constant.

You can use [`IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) when selecting the data to concatenate other column values in case value is `null`. For example:

```
SELECT IFNULL(fullname, firstname || ' ' || lastname) ...
```